# JSON.NET Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'responseData',

Tags: json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize this [link](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blogs) , but I keep getting this error.

**Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'responseData'.**

From what i have googled, the problem seems to be the setup of my object I'm trying to deserialize into. Below is my class:

```
  public class FeedSearchResult
{
    [JsonProperty("responseData")]
    public String ResponseData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("query")]
    public String Query { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entries")]
    public string[] Entries { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("responseDetails")]
    public object ResponseDetails { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("responseStatus")]
    public String ResponseStatsu { get; set; }
}

public class ResultItem
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public String Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("link")]
    public String Link { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my class? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your data model doesn't really match the returned JSON; `responseData` is an object but you have it as a string instead.  Upload the JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ to get a corrected data model.

Comment: Dang. Should've searched for a tool like that in the first  place to be honest. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2):

Your data model only has two levels of nesting, but the JSON returned has three.  If you look at the formatted JSON using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you will see:

```
{
   "responseData":{
      "query":"Official Google Blogs",
      "entries":[
         {
            "url":"https://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default",
            "title":"\u003cb\u003eOfficial Google Blog\u003c/b\u003e",
            "contentSnippet":"\u003cb\u003eOfficial\u003c/b\u003e weblog, with news of new products, events and glimpses of life inside \u003cbr\u003e\n\u003cb\u003eGoogle\u003c/b\u003e.",
            "link":"https://googleblog.blogspot.com/"
         },
```

In particular your data model has `responseData` as a `String` when it needs to be a contained object.  This is the specific cause of the exception.

If you upload the JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ you will get the following data model, which can be used to deserialize this JSON:

```
public class ResultItem
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string contentSnippet { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseData
{
    public string query { get; set; }
    public List<ResultItem> entries { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ResponseData responseData { get; set; }
    //Omitted since type is unclear.
    //public object responseDetails { get; set; } 
    public int responseStatus { get; set; }
}
```